# Why are Google Mercator and UTM rotated towards each other?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Being a self-taught GIS user, I struggled a while before getting the grips on map projections. But now this: because I like to use OpenStreetMap as a background layer for orientation, I have saved my shapefiles all in EPSG:3857 ("Google Mercator").

However, if I want to create a grid of 10×10m² grid cells, I had to convert one of the layers to UTM (zone N32, EPSG:32632) for the spacing to be correct. What surprised me when reactivating the OTF conversion, that the grid had **rotated**:

[image: two map snippets, one in EPSG:32632, the other reprojected to EPSG:3857]

I would have expected minor distortion or even scaling, but **why is North not identical (straight up) for both projections**?

*For reference: the excerpt shown is from [48.18714° N, 12.14092° E](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=19/48.18714/12.14092&layers=N).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

North is identical in both systems only for the central meridian of the UTM projection.

All other meridians are bended in (universal) transverse mercator, while they are straight up north in Mercator projection.

The rotation direction depends on whether you are east or west of your central meridian.